# Android : get data from MySQL using 'where' condition

Tags: java, php, android, android-studio, mysqli

I am trying to get data from MySQL database to my android app using **where** condition. I already create a method for get data. This method give me all data as a string array from a single column.
Look the bellow method :

```
String adress = "http://myserver_link/get_data.php";
InputStream inputStream = null;
String line = null, result = null, data[];

private void get_data(){
    try {
        URL url = new URL(adress);
        HttpURLConnection httpsURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpsURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(httpsURLConnection.getInputStream());

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // read input stream into a string
    try{
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
        }

        inputStream.close();
        result = stringBuilder.toString();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Parse json data
    try{
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;

        data = new String[jsonArray.length()];
        for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            data[i] = jsonObject.getString("user_adress"); // column name
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is my get data java method. And my **get_data.php** code is :

```
<?php 
require "conn.php";

$query = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from android_data");

if ($query) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $flag[] = $row;
    }
    print(json_encode($flag));
}

$conn->close();
 ?>
```

Now I want to write my **get_data.php** file like bellow :

```
<?php 
require "conn.php";

$user_name = $_POST["username"];

$query = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from android_data where username='$user_name'");

if ($query) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $flag[] = $row;
    }
    print(json_encode($flag));
}

$conn->close();
 ?>
```

But how I can send username using **get_data()** java method from my app?

Comment: You should look into prepared statements as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably send this as a parameter on the URL...

```
String adress = "http://myserver_link/get_data.php?username=xxxxx";
```

Not done Java for a while, but you can create this string using the appropriate value for xxxxx.

This will then be passed in as `$_GET["username"]` instead of `$_POST["username"]`.  So just replace this line

```
$user_name = $_POST["username"];
```

with

```
$user_name = $_GET["username"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can change the Request method to POST in your Java code.